# How to get OpenCL working on new Pheonix APU?

Tags: amd-graphics, gpu-driver, opencl, darktable

I recently call an HP ZBook Firefly 14 G10 A my own. It's the successor of an older Thinkpad with Intel UHD GPU that has become a bit slow for my usecase. But it runs OpenCL in darktable smoothly. Both run Kubuntu 23.10 on Wayland.

My System has currently 16GB of DDR5 RAM with a clock speed of 5600 Mhz (will upgrade to 32GB soon), the Ryzen 7 Pro 7840HS, with 8 Zen 4 cores. GPU is the built-in Radeon 780M RDNA3 GPU. In UEFI Firmware settings I've chosen "Gaming optimized" for VRAM. I'm really amazed by this device. It runs XP12 in FHD on lower settings with 30-40 FPS which is quite impressive regarding that this is just mobile iGPU.

I just edited some RAWs in darktable and wondered about the extreme CPU usage. So, I took a look at the "processing" settings where I shockingly recognised that OpenCL wasn't enabled and greyed out.

By searching on the internet about this issue I found the command "darktable-cltest" which returns me the following:

```
     0,0179 [dt_get_sysresource_level] switched to 1 as `default'
 0,0180   total mem:       13740MB
 0,0180   mipmap cache:    1717MB
 0,0180   available mem:   6870MB
 0,0180   singlebuff:      107MB
 0,0180   OpenCL tune mem: OFF
 0,0180   OpenCL pinned:   OFF
 [opencl_init] opencl related configuration options:
 [opencl_init] opencl: ON
 [opencl_init] opencl_scheduling_profile: 'default'
 [opencl_init] opencl_library: 'default path'
 [opencl_init] opencl_device_priority: '*/!0,*/*/*/!0,*'
 [opencl_init] opencl_mandatory_timeout: 400
 [opencl_init] opencl library 'libOpenCL' found on your system and loaded
 [opencl_init] found 4 platforms
 [opencl_init] platform 2 is not FULL_PROFILE
 [opencl_init] no devices found for Mesa/X.org (vendor) - rusticl (name)
 [opencl_init] found 2 devices
 
 [dt_opencl_device_init]
    DEVICE:                   0: 'AMD Radeon Graphics (gfx1103_r1, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.54, 6.5.0-14-generic)'
 PLATFORM NAME & VENDOR:   Clover, Mesa
 CANONICAL NAME:           cloveramdradeongraphics
 DRIVER VERSION:           23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1
 DEVICE VERSION:           OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1
 DEVICE_TYPE:              GPU
 *** insufficient device version ***
 
 [dt_opencl_device_init]
 DEVICE:                   1: 'AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 7840HS w/ Radeon 780M Graphics '
 PLATFORM NAME & VENDOR:   Intel(R) OpenCL, Intel(R) Corporation
 CANONICAL NAME:           intelropenclamdryzen7pro7840hswradeon780mgraphics
 DRIVER VERSION:           2023.16.12.0.12_195853.xmain-hotfix
 DEVICE VERSION:           OpenCL 3.0 (Build 0)
 DEVICE_TYPE:              CPU
 GLOBAL MEM SIZE:          13741 MB
 MAX MEM ALLOC:            6870 MB
 MAX IMAGE SIZE:           16384 x 16384
 MAX WORK GROUP SIZE:      8192
 MAX WORK ITEM DIMENSIONS: 3
 MAX WORK ITEM SIZES:      [ 8192 8192 8192 ]
 ASYNC PIXELPIPE:          NO
 PINNED MEMORY TRANSFER:   NO
 MEMORY TUNING:            NO
 FORCED HEADROOM:          400
 AVOID ATOMICS:            NO
 MICRO NAP:                1000
 ROUNDUP WIDTH:            16
 ROUNDUP HEIGHT:           16
 CHECK EVENT HANDLES:      128
 TILING ADVANTAGE:         0.000
 DEFAULT DEVICE:           NO
 *** marked as disabled ***
 [opencl_init] no suitable devices found.
 [opencl_init] FINALLY: opencl is NOT AVAILABLE and NOT ENABLED.
```

Okay, it tells me that it has actually found theoretically relevant devices one of whom is my GPU and the other one seems to be a software renderer on the CPU.
Both are assessed as ineligible but, why? Of course, the second "device" isn't properly a device and perhaps using a COU to software render OpenCL will not give a decent boost in performance.

But what's about the GPU? It bothers me a lot that the information printed over the GPU is that sparse. There are so many informations missing.

I mean I have neither exotic hardware nor an exotic OS. It would be strange if I was alone with this problem. Whats the issue with OpenCL on Ryzen APUs so far? What packages do we need?